# R write file with names of the objects

Tags: r

Consider this:
I have vector `fav.activities` with names of the objects:

```
fav.activities <- c("swiming", "basketball", "baseball", "football")  
names(fav.activities) <- c("Tom", "Ben", "Paul", "Ann")
```

I want to save the whole file now. Used

```
write(fav.activities)
```

But names of the objects aren't saved. How should I do this?

Comment: you could use `save()` function, if it answers your needs.

Comment: Firstly, please be more careful and include valid R code without errors into your Question. Not only did you misspell the `fav.activities` object name, you didn't quote the strings when creating the vector. I fixed these and the formatting mistake too. Second, can you clarify if you want to write this out to a text file for use in other software or to just store the vector on disk for use in later R sessions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to save your data in text format, use:

```
write.table(fav.activities, file = "filename.txt", col.names = FALSE)
```

To restore the object from the text file:

```
dat <- read.table("filename.txt", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
fav.activities <- structure(dat[ , 2], .Names = dat[ , 1])
```

If you want to save a representation of the R object, use:

```
save(fav.activities, file = "filename.RData")
```

To restore the object:

```
load("filename.RData")
```

Comment: +1 Apologies, you are right. Was reading a file written with different arguments to check what was going on. You might wish to add that `read.table()` call to your answer via an edit.

Comment: I update my answer with information how the object can be restored.

Answer (score 3):

`write()` uses `cat()` and that drops the `"names"` attribute when sending the output to the screen/file:

```
R> cat(fav.activities)
swiming basketball baseball footballR>
```

If you want the vector read out to a text/delimited file, one option is to coerce to a matrix and use `write.table()`:

```
R> write.table(t(as.matrix(fav.activities)), "foo.txt", row.names = FALSE)
R> readLines("foo.txt")
[1] "\"Tom\" \"Ben\" \"Paul\" \"Ann\""                    
[2] "\"swiming\" \"basketball\" \"baseball\" \"football\""
```

The extra `\"` are just how R prints the strings to the console. From my OS the file looks like this:

```
$ cat foo.txt
"Tom" "Ben" "Paul" "Ann"
"swiming" "basketball" "baseball" "football"
```

I.e. it is a space separated file. Other separators can be defined; see `?write.table`.

If you just want to read the vector out for use in a later R session, then `save()` or `saveRDS()` are two options:

```
ls()
save(fav.activities, file = "obj.rda")
rm(list = ls())
load("obj.rda")
ls()
saveRDS(fav.activities, file = "obj2.rds")
new.fav <- readRDS("obj2.rds")
ls()
all.equal(fav.activities, new.fav)
```

With this output:

```
R> ls()
[1] "fav.activities"
R> save(fav.activities, file = "obj.rda")
R> rm(list = ls())
R> load("obj.rda")
R> ls()
[1] "fav.activities"
R> saveRDS(fav.activities, file = "obj2.rds")
R> new.fav <- readRDS("obj2.rds")
R> ls()
[1] "fav.activities" "new.fav"       
R> all.equal(fav.activities, new.fav)
[1] TRUE
```

The main difference between `save()` and `saveRDS()` is that the former save the object and it's name so can only ever be restored with the same object name. Whereas `saveRDS()` just serialises the object which then has to be assigned to an object upon loading the serialised object into an R session.